# CSS modification causes mobile/tablet scrollbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

in the past couple of days I've been trying to stretch a certain section to fill the entire container, and I got it working. Problem is, in mobile/tablet a left-right scroll bar appears and it also messes up the sticky header.

Page that I stretched: https://roi.pub/about-me/ 
Code I used:

```
#primary .container {
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;}

.layout-content.boxed #primary {
padding: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.layout-content.boxed #primary{padding: 0 !important;}
}
```

And here's what a page looks like prior to stretching: https://roi.pub/elementor-2620/ I'm just trying to get the content to fill the white container without messing things up.

Advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You removed padding from the .container class, which is what needs to be there for bootstrap to work like it should.

***NOTE*** Never override bootstrap added classes, if you want to change how bootstrap work, pull in sass/less version and do your stuff there.
On the .row bootstrap use -15px on left and right to accommodate for padding of 15px on left and right of the .container, thus when you remove padding from .container you get mess, don't override bootstrap.

```
#primary .container {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

.container needs to have padding of 15px, those lines above is what makes your horizontal scrollbar. When I remove them everything work fine.

If you are not bothered with overrding bootstrap (you should) instead of setting padding to zero on the .container you need to set padding to zero on the columns itself. Like this.

```
.full-width {
  padding: 0;
}
```

You already have that class, on the  element that also have .col from bootstrap.

**GENERAL COMMENT**
If you find yourself in a need to change bootstrap setting you should use sass/less to alter the setting, but if you find yourself in a need to change bootstrap behavior then DON'T use bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks Nikola. I tried removing this part but I'm still left with the scrollbar.

Comment: Take a look now.I updated the answer, hope you don't mind for extra tips about overriding bootstrap. ;)

Comment: So why shouldn't I alter bootstrap? What stands behind it?

Comment: It is a long list of why not. But ask yourself this, is altering React or Angular something good? Not, why would not be the same for css framework? You see, you would not be in this situation in the first place if you didn't alter BS.
There is many many more reasons why not to alter frameworks/libs in general, but I would need a blog post about it. :)
If you build something that is not covered by BS (or any other lib/fw) simple do not use that lib/fw. Create your own, or search for more. Chose the right tool, and it is not always the most popular that is the best fit for the job.

Comment: Also, did it worked for you? If yes, please consider accepting my answer, thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks man, but I'm still left with the scrollbar. Both with the first code, the second (and when both of them together.)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Your problem has appeared from the 1170px width of the screen (this is the width of your theme too).
so there are two solutions

1. Remove the -15px from the margin from the max-width media query: 1170px, and also remove the `#primary #content #main` paddding

   @media (max-width: 1170px){

   ```
   #primary #content #main {
       padding-left: 0; 
       padding-right: 0; 
   }

   #primary #content {
       margin-left: 0; 
       margin-right: 0; 
   }
   ```

   }
2. Either apply this code `#primary .container {overflow: hidden;}` on the container to hide any overwriting

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. You wrote in the media query max-width 767px because that's what's stated in the mobile/tablet stylesheet? Also, your code did fix the problem in mobile view, but in tablet I still encounter the scrollbar...

Comment: so, just add the same classes in the media query ```@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {...}```

Comment: I just edited my answer by putting the CSS code to put as it is

Comment: Mahmoud, you're the man. After many days of frustrations I got it sort out! Thank you. Now, just so I understand your code for next time use: the "max-width: 991px" you set to be this number because the white container is 991px wide?

Comment: 991px is the interval from which we apply the CSS code. your problem is due to the right-and-left margin -15px of the Bootstrap's row class that overwrites the screen when the width of the screen and lower the width of your theme

Comment: you can add ```#primary .container {overflow: hidden;}``` to hide this overwrite for all resolutions

Comment: I didn't quite understand you. What would the last string give me if I add it?